# Debbuging SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging

I have a problem debugging some problem.

I started thread in wordpress.stackexchange.com thinking that I get more wordpress related debugging suggestions but went with totally different way.

You can see topic here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123394/some-ways-to-debug-code

with update: `DELETE FROM wp_bp_activity WHERE item_id = 0`

My Question is SQL related: Can `DELETE` statement be triggered from something then `DELETE` query? for example I rememeber having a bad query which was deleting everything. (but that was everything and not an `if` statment)

So to extend this question: If I search every query with `DELETE FROM` will I find it for sure? Can this be written differently? Because for now, I can't find it.

Comment: [MySQL triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)?

Comment: Additional tuples could get deleted due to a ON DELETE CASCADE in the schema.  Otherwise the WHERE clause or a trigger could be the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) is also used to DELETE all the records from a table.

You can also have some kind of foreign key cascading, that is triggering the delete in that table. More [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Addicionally, make sure to search on the database also, on triggers and on stored procedures

One other option is that they were updated to a different value than the one you are looking for.